# Calling load-theme with interactive input

Tags: call-interactively

I want to call `load-theme` within a function.  Whilst it is supposed to give an interactive input using `completing-read`, just calling `load-theme` gives an error and the interactive input is not activated.  What can I do to get the interactive equivalent behaviour ?

```
  (pcase actm
    ("load-theme"       (load-theme))
    ("customize-themes" (customize-themes)))
```

Comment: Use `call-interactively`?

Comment: I wonder whether to call `(call-interactively 'load-theme)` or  `(call-interactively #'load-theme)`.

Comment: Try them both out: it takes 10 seconds, 15 at most. Then read the doc string of `call-interactively`.

Comment: I get the same thing when I do both in Lisp Interaction `C-x e`.